# rsync weird behaviour

Tags: ssh, rsync, permission-denied

I have to sync some folders from a linux server, to another.
We have created the RSA-Key and the authentication goes well.

When we launch an rsync command, some of the files gave birth to errors like:

- *rsync: readlink "/var/www/sestantemultimedia.it/xxecommerce/pub/.htaccess" failed: Permission denied (13)*

Now, the directory /var/ (as well as other subdirectory) have the permits set to 755.
The files into the last directories have permits set like 644.

So, theoretically, permits as set right and I can read from the other server and copy my files.

What I am missing?

Comment: an initial question would be what user you are using for the rsync command? Does this user have the correct read access/permissions for the files its trying to access?

Comment: If you read with attention, you'll find that the other group (so, "the rest of the world" have read/execute permits. So, indipendently on wich user is launch that command, the sync have to be possibile. We do something like that, because we accept only ssh-connection on that server, so if you haven't the key and the passphrase, you can't do anything.

Comment: I think i mispoke previously, what i meant was not that the user running rsyc has access rights to the server but access rights to file on the server. Example: You may decide to run the rsync using support  (instead of system) but support does not have permissions on the other server to read the .htaccess file.

Comment: You told me exactly the same thing. I repet: on filesystem of server where i want to take files, the permits are setted for other (and that user is INTO other group) in a read/exec. way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just figured it out.

Someone (because we work together as a team) had done a change on the "final folder" so that "apache" user's group can't execute (so can't traverse) the folder itself.

In that way, although it is possibile for "other group" to execute, the sum of permits that we receive (we were into "apache" group) isn't enough for "execute" the folder and retrive the file.

We just change that scenario and now it works properly!